# How to use inject() in a Pipe with Angular 14?

Tags: angular, angular-injector

I'm trying to ion inject a service into a pipe. Usually, `inject(...)` works fine, but in a pipe context I'm getting the error:

```
Error: NG0203: inject() must be called from an injection context such as a constructor, a factory function, a field initializer, or a function used with `EnvironmentInjector#runInContext`
```

What I'm doing wrong or how can I get it to work?

The service works fine when I put the dependency in the constructor, like `constructor(private service: CheckboxFilterPipe)`, but I want to use it now in the component code (using `transform()` programmatically), it's no option to write the dependency in the constructor anymore.

```
@Pipe({
    name: 'checkboxFilter',
    pure: true,
})
export class CheckboxFilterPipe implements PipeTransform {
    /** */
    private service = inject(CheckboxFilterService);

    constructor() {}

    transform(items: Array<any>, filter: IFilterSettings, defaultFilter?: IFilterDefaults): any {
        this.service.init();
        return this.service.doFilter(items, filter, defaultFilter);
    }
}
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Tried in StackBlitz, no errors: https://angular-ivy-ecxh8y.stackblitz.io

Comment: @Eugene the stackblitz is not accessible (loads forever).

Comment: Hm, so can you provide stackblitz or repo?

Comment: @Eugene unfortunately, not really. It's part of a huge project and the effort to separate is very high. But you said that it was working fine on your site with `inject(...)`?

Comment: Yep, it's ok for me with `inject`

Answer (score 5):

If you are using Angular 14.1 version. you can use runInContext API. which will allow you to call inject inside function body

**pipe.ts**

```
import {
  EnvironmentInjector,
  inject,
  Pipe,
  PipeTransform,
} from '@angular/core';
import { UtilServiceService } from './util-service.service';

@Pipe({
  name: 'demo',
})
export class DemoPipe implements PipeTransform {
  private environment = inject(EnvironmentInjector);

  transform(value: any, args?: any): any {
    return this.environment.runInContext(() => {
      return inject(UtilServiceService).filterData(value);
    });
  }
}
```

**[Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-xtektg?file=src/app/demo.pipe.ts)**

**[For More Info](https://netbasal.com/getting-to-know-the-runincontext-api-in-angular-f8996d7e00da)**

Comment: Thank you for this hint. I'll give it a try. Currently, I'm still on 14.0. So it's time to update...

Comment: You are welcome! To solve above error only they have introduced runInContext. In future version of angular also depend on this api:https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/46682

Comment: Sorry but this answer does not really make sense... If he can't inject the CheckBoxFilterService in his pipe, he won't be able to inject EnvironmentInjector... Last time I had the issue was because I was using a library linked via `npm link` and I had to add the `preserveSymLinks` in the consumer app.

Comment: @ssougnez hi, As per original post he was getting error while using inject function inside transform method. May be I was wrong let Lars confirm whether this solution working or not.